# Get IIS settings (located in web.config) from remote server using WMI or other secure methods

Tags: c#, iis, web-config, wmi

I'm trying to programmatically read (and only read) various IIS settings from **remote** servers (Win 2k8/IIS7 , or Win2k12/IIS8).
Have tried but eventually gave up on Microsoft.Web.Administration and WebConfigurationManager methods, because they require certain security "flexibility", which isn't feasible for me.

I found WMI impersonation capabilities the most adequate, and I am able to get the settings which reside within ApplicationHost.config file.

So far I've not been able to find a way to use WMI to read from the web.config file at the virtual directory level.
Currently I'm looking to read Authentication settings - "mode", and the various attributes of that mode.

To illustrate, this is the portion of the web.config file I'm interested in (example for Forms Authentication):

`<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <authentication mode="Forms">
            <forms loginUrl="~/Login.aspx" name=".ASPXAUTH" timeout="360" />
        </authentication>
    <system.webServer>
</configuration>`

Is there a way to reach this data using WMI?
Or can you think of another (secure) method to achieve this goal?

Appreciate the help!

**EDIT** found the right namespace and posted it in an answer

Answer (score 0):

The `WMI` doesn't provide any class to read the content of a file.... but for your particular case you can check the [IIS WMI Provider](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms525265(v=vs.90).aspx) reference and try something like the [IIsWebFileSetting](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms525661(v=vs.90).aspx) class.

Comment: Maybe I should have phrased it differently. I know WMI doesn't read contents of files. I just couldn't find reference to the settings I was looking for (that are specifically found in the web.config rather than applictaionHost.config) in the IIS WMI Provider. I'll check out the IISWebFileSetting class though, Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I was using the wrong WMI Namespace (MicrosoftIISv2).
The namespace I should've been using is WebAdministration. It has access to the properties I'm looking for (specifically those related to Forms Authentication). More info here - http://wutils.com/wmi/root/webadministration

I'm now facing another problem, where I'm able to connect to this namespace on one machine and query for data, but not on another (seemingly identical) machine.
Guess that's a subject for a different question, though.